# Unable to fathom logic expression for use in if... else... statement Python

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

I'm attempting a little game and I need to use some logic to check usage on board positions in order to set a bool validMove flag.  I appreciate this isn't expert level code and there is certainly a better way of doing it, but this is the code I have written and is what I am using.  I need to check for the instance of a space or an underscore at a specific point in a list.  When I check for a space the code works, when I check for an underscore the code works, but when I try checking for both conditions with an or statement, the code fails.  Could an expert advise what I am doing wrong please.  Many thanks.

This code checking for an underscore works...

```
    while not valid_move:
    # check for unoccupied position
    if board[x][y] != '_':
        valid_move = False
        print('Invalid move detected.')
        print(board[x][y])
        get_user_input()
        getCoordinates(position)
    else:
        print('Valid move...')
        valid_move = True
        # update board with player position
        board[x][y] = player
```

This same code checking for a space works...

```
    while not valid_move:
    # check for unoccupied position
    if board[x][y] != ' ':
        valid_move = False
        print('Invalid move detected.')
        print(board[x][y])
        get_user_input()
        getCoordinates(position)
    else:
        print('Valid move...')
        valid_move = True
        # update board with player position
        board[x][y] = player
```

This code using on or statement checking for both, fails...

```
    while not valid_move:
    # check for unoccupied position
    if (board[x][y] != ' ') or (board[x][y] != '_'):
        valid_move = False
        print('Invalid move detected.')
        print(board[x][y])
        get_user_input()
        getCoordinates(position)
    else:
        print('Valid move...')
        valid_move = True
        # update board with player position
        board[x][y] = player
```

Comment: Turn that ``or`` into an ``and``?

Comment: OMG!!!! is it really as simple as that @MikeScotty ...? I still can't fathom how that logic works with AND instead of OR, but it appears to work, thank you muchly.

Comment: You're welcome. You could also check out the ``in`` / ``not in`` operator. e.g. ``if (board[x][y] not in ' _')`` - since a string is also an iterable. If string wasn't an iterable you'd have to do ``if (board[x][y] not in (' ', '_'))``